# Oracle error ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I got an error while creating this table.

Here are the `course` and `slide` tables:

```
create table course 
(
    course_num number(10),
    course_name char(10),

    primary key (course_num)
);

create table slide 
(
    serial_no number(10), 
    s_writer char(10),
    s_title char(10), 
    subject char(10),
    regist_num number (10),

    primary key (serial_no, s_writer, s_title),
    foreign key (regist_num) references student(registration_number)
);
```

What should I do ?

[image]

Comment: You haven't defined `student`.

Comment: it's part of a project I didn't notice that I have to share it all. but it's working now check Monika's comment it's the solution

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text for all code, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key should be in one definition, like this:

```
create table s_belong_to(
s_serial_no number(10),
writer char(10), 
title char(10), 

foreign key(s_serial_no, writer, title) references slide(serial_no,s_writer, s_title),
primary key (s_serial_no, writer, title)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first table `course` has two columns `course_num`.  That is an error.

The second table has a foreign key reference to a non-existent column.  That is an error.  The foreign key reference should be to the primary key of a table.

Comment: the course table and slide table has no errors, the course table has two cols course name and course number. and the slide table has a column who is reference two student table I forgot to share the student table but all the tables are without any errors except s_belong_to